# Information content associated with an outcome

Tags: probability, information-theory

I have the following exam question for a multimedia exam in college:

> Assume that you roll a single ordinary six-sided die twice, and
>   observe that the  second number rolled is greater than the first.  In
>   an information theoretic sense, what is the information content
>   associated  with this outcome?

If the information content associated with an event is -log2Pe (- log to base 2 times probability of event e), would the following be true:

```
First Roll:  -log2( 1 / 5 )  //First number rolled can be any number except 6
Second Roll: -log2( 1 / 5 )  //Second number can be any number but the first
```

Therefore the information content of this outcome =

-(log(1/5)/log(2)) + -(log(1/5)/log(2)) = 4.64385618977

or would it be

x = probability of second roll given the first

-log(x / log(2))

If that is the case, how do I work out the value of x.

Comment: This is not a research-level question in theoretical CS. See the [FAQ].   Please click "flag" to ask that your question be moved to cs.stackexchange.com (Computer Science.SE).

Comment: Moving to math.SE. this  question is out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the second roll ist greater than the first is $\frac{15}{36}=\frac{5}{12}$. You can calculate the information content as $-\log_2 p$ then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how did you work out 15/36?

Comment: Of the $36=6\cdot 6$ outcomes from two dice, there are $6$ with numbers equal, of the remaining $30$ exactly half have the second die greater.